# Make WP 8.1 HTML app window not dragable

Tags: javascript, css, windows-phone-8

I created a windows phone app, but when you scroll up (with your finger) it brings the page up like IE would. As in the whole window moves.

**It looks like this by default**:

[image: default]

**But when I drag the list to it's max potential (in this case straight down) this occurs:**

[image: dragged]

Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution here would be to make the top bar which you would like to keep in place a separate element from the list.  Then it will stay at the top and the list under would scroll without pulling the "header" down also.

You may want to absolutely position the "header" and offset the list by the vertical height of said "header".

Remove

```
-ms-scroll-translation: vertical-to-horizontal;
```

from the html,body and add it to the list element.

Comment: I know I didn't state this, but it is a separate element.

Comment: The html,body css rule mentioned above for the -ms-scroll-transition is causing the scrolling of the entire document which is allowing the "header" to also scroll

Comment: Ohhhh, didn't realize that. Yea, thanks. Suppose this is a somewhat better way of answering then. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After deciding to check `/css/ui-themed.css` I found this at the top:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
  -ms-scroll-translation: vertical-to-horizontal;
}
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
 -ms-content-zooming: none;
}
```

Seems to have solved the problem, however I think I have narrowed it down too the `overflow:hidden` there.

Regardless this has solved the problem for me.